# Vue.js 2 v-for loop called to infinite

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

On my vue.js application I want to draw several rectangles (the number depends on a array length) and lines beetween them. For that I have 4 data x, y, nextX, netxY which will be updated during the drawing progressing.

Here my data

```
data () {
    return {
        x: 25,
        y: 25,
        nextX: null,
        nextY: null,
        elemntList: []
    }
}
```

Here my methods

```
<div v-for="element in elementsList" v-bind:key="element.model">
    <v-rect :config="getConfigRect()"></v-rect>

    {{ $calculNextPosition(element.model) }}

    <v-line :config="getConfigLine()"></v-line>

    {{ $setOriginOnNextPosition() }}
</div>
```

getConfigRect must have x and y parameters

To draw a line I need the future position where the next rectrangle will be drawn
So, getConfig Line must have x and y parameters (start point) and nextX and nextY parameters (end point).

```
  methods: {
    $calculNextPosition: function() {
        this.nextX = this.x + 100;
        this.nextY = this.y;
    },
    $setOriginOnNextPosition: function() {
        this.x = this.nextX;
        this.y = this.nextY;

        this.nextX = null;
        this.nextY = null;
    },
    getConfigRect: function() {
        return {
            x: this.x,
            y: this.y,
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
            fill: 'white',
            stroke: '#016FBF',
            strokeWidth: 2,
            offset: 10
       }
    },
    getConfigLine: function() {
        return  {
            points: [this.x, this.y, this.nextX, this.nextY],
            stroke: 'red',
            strokeWidth: 15,
            offset: 20
       } 
    },
}
```

This simple code prepare the next rectangle 100 pixel on the left than the previous. However my v-for loop is called to infinite. The problem is due to the $setOriginOnNextPosition function. If I remove that method the loop is called only once.

Why my v-for loop is called again and again ?
If I have to use computed methods, how can I refactore my code to succeed ?

EDIT: Maybe resetting my x and y data reload the entire view and call again the loop ...

Comment: What do you mean by always called? Those methods will be called for each element in `elementsList`. It isn't clear to me what you are seeing, but it seems like you are trying to perform calculations in the html which should not be there. I suggest doing any configuration of your elements list completely in javascript, then have the html simply display what is already calculated.

Comment: Thank's to you anwser. I added precisions to my problem. It's my v-for loop which is called to a infinite due to the method setOriginOnNextPosition

Comment: what side effects does getConfigLine have?  Maybe include that code?

Comment: Where are you using element.model in calculNextPosition(...?)

Comment: I don't use my element.model, I forget to delete it. I updated my post

Comment: How is elementsList being populated and is it being modified anywhere?

Comment: elementsList is populated in mounted() and never being modified :/ The problem came to my function $setOriginOnNextPosition. that's the reason of my post editing

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can rely on changing the model state during v-for, but maybe someone with some real vue.js chops might know how that can be done.

> If I have to use computed methods, how can I refactor my code to succeed ?

One thing you could do is get an index from v-for like this:

```
<div v-for="(element, index) in elementsList" v-bind:key="element.model">
```

Then just pass `index` to your computation so you don't need to rely on changing state while v-for is running.

So, instead of updating `x` and `y` in the v-for loop, compute what `x` and `y` would be from the index.

it looks like `y` never changes, so you can refer to `this.y`.

For `x`, it increments every time by 100, so you could have a method to compute what x would be:

```
methods: {
    computeX(index) {
        return this.x + 100 * index;
    }
}
```

Then use `this.x1(index)` in place of `this.x` in your getConfigRect and getConfigLine methods:

```
getConfigRect: function(index) {
    return {
        x: this.x1(index + 1),
        y: this.y,
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
        fill: 'white',
        stroke: '#016FBF',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        offset: 10
   }
},
getConfigLine: function(index) {
    return  {
        points: [this.computeX(index + 1), this.y, this.computeX(index), this.nextY],
        stroke: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 15,
        offset: 20
   } 
},
```

Take this as an example (no way I can test it in a reasonable amount of time).  It should give you an idea.

Comment: I don't have for the moment computed methods and I beginner in vue.js framework. I don't really understand what is your solution

Comment: I think what Jim is trying to say, is that you should not be modifying your model (x, y....) inside your loop. These things should be done in your javascript, ideally 'before' rendering the html.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but I would do it something like this. Basically, it loops a number of times and passes the current loop number (I do i-1 because v-for starts the values at 1, and using 0 to start makes the calculations nicer) to the getConfig methods. The getConfig methods calculate the next position based on the start value, the i value, and the step value.

HTML:

```
<div v-for="i in numElems">
    <v-rect :config="getConfigRect(i-1)"></v-rect>

    <v-line :config="getConfigLine(i-1)"></v-line>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
data() {
    return {
        startX: 25,
        startY: 25,
        stepX: 100,
        numElems: 4
    }
},

methods: {
    getConfigRect: function(i) {
        return {
            x: this.getX(i),
            y: this.getY(i),
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
            fill: 'white',
            stroke: '#016FBF',
            strokeWidth: 2,
            offset: 10
       }
    },

    getConfigLine: function(i) {
        return  {
            points: [this.getX(i), this.getY(i), this.getX(i+1), this.getY(i+1)],
            stroke: 'red',
            strokeWidth: 15,
            offset: 20
       } 
    },

    getX: function(i) {
        return this.$data.startX + i * this.$data.stepX;
    },

    getY: function(i) {
        return this.$data.startY;
    }
}
```